# BASH - Compare string output from Date

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

I'm trying to use a timestamp to rotate log files each day.  Store the last date-string and then for my infinite loop (currently sleeping every 5 mins) generate a new date and compare the two.  If they are equal, it's the same day and writes to the same log file.  If the values are different, writes to a new log file but before those new writes occur, tar the previous day up.  **My date-string eqaulity conditional isn't evaluating as I'd expect and I'm asking why this is:**

```
lastdate=$(date +%Y%m%d)
while true
do
   curdate=$(date +%Y%m%d)

   echo "${lastdate}, ${curdate}"

   if [ "$lastdate" != "$curdate" ]; then
      ## do tar
      lastdate="$curdate"
   fi

   du >> "disk_du_${lastdate}.log"

   sleep 300
done
```

For the section in question, my echo statement shows both strings as having the same value but the conditional always runs even though I'm testing for inequality (or at least, that's the intent).  I've tried different variations of the conditonal:

```
if [[ "$lastdate" != "$curdate" ]]; then
if [ $lastdate != $curdate ]; then
if [[ $lastdate != $curdate ]]; then
if [ "${lastdate}" != "${curdate}" ]; then
```

...but the conditional always runs even though the strings always show the same value.  I based structuring the condtional off of:  http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html, Example 7-5 so I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.  TIA.

Comment: Works for me.  I suggest you run with `bash -x script-name` to see the exact expansions.  BTW, you are sleeping for 500 seconds (just over 8 minutes), not 5 minutes (which is 300 seconds).

Comment: yeah that was a mistake in the repro of the script, the script has 300 seconds... ty for pointing that out and updated...

Comment: Try it with the `-x` trace, it should show everything that is happening.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion and report back.  ty.

Comment: As an aside, the ABS is a dubious resource, though I didn't spot any obvious errors in the specific example you mentioned.

Comment: Does your script file by any chance contain DOS line endings? `cat -v` and look for `^M` in the output.

Comment: How do you know the conditional is executed? There's no `else` so `du`command will always be executed.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz -- I know it executes because a tar is executed on every cycle of the loop.  My #do tar in the post is just a placeholder for my actual tar command.

Comment: Did you tried with `-ne` instead of `!=`. Your date looks like an integer anyway. Also, there's no point in running it all the time since the condition should be met around midnight only.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to have a check on your BASH

TEST:

GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

**It's working:**

```
#!/bin/bash
lastdate=$(date +%Y%m%d)
while true
do
   curdate=$(date +%Y%m%d)

   echo "${lastdate}, ${curdate}"

   if [ "$lastdate" != "$curdate" ]; then
      ## do tar
      lastdate="$curdate"
      echo "TRUE"
   else
      echo "FALSE"
   fi
   sleep 5
done
```

OUT:

```
20180404, 20180404
FALSE
20180404, 20180404
FALSE
20180404, 20180404
FALSE
20180404, 20180404
FALSE
20180404, 20180404
FALSE
20180404, 20180404
FALSE
20180404, 20180404
FALSE
20180404, 20180404
FALSE
```